# Ember 3 Computed Properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, properties, migration

I'm trying to migrate from ember 2 to ember 3, and i have problems with computed properties.

Before, i had this kind of computed properties in a component :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

totalPrice: Ember.computed('attr1', 'attr2', function() {
    return this.attr1 + this.attr2;
})
```

and i could do in the hbs template something like :

```
Total : {{totalPrice}}
```

In the new version of ember, i have this :

```
import { computed, set } from '@ember/object';

totalPrice: computed('attr1', 'attr2', function() {
   return this.attr1 + this.attr2;
})
```

But in the template, the totalPrice property is display as `[object]` and not with the value. Am i missing something ?

Comment: That's usually what happens when you return a promise into a template. Do you, by chance, have `async function` in your real code?

Comment: no i don't have any async function in my code, but maybe i missed something

Comment: @Gemkodor Please verify my answer if you find my solution was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `function` instead of an arrow function, because with arrow functions, the `this` is lost.

with computed's `function` keeps the `this` referencing the component instance.

```
computed('attr1', 'attr2', function() {
   return this.attr1 && this.attr2;
})
```

Comment: In fact i already used the function instead of an arrow function, i made a mistake in my description of the problem. I edited the description of my problem, in fact my problem is more "how access the computed property in the template". After my migration, it's displayed as [object] in the template, and i don't understand why

Comment: what version of ember are you using? native getters weren't added until ember 3.1 I think

Comment: i'm using ember 3.8

Comment: can you share what `this.attr1`  and `this.attr2` are?  or replicate on http://ember-twiddle.com/ ?

Comment: That's weird, i tried to replicate on ember-twiddle but it works. I have something similar to : https://ember-twiddle.com/0deff5b0c1321cba4fe5ee4142429c53?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route Except that in my case, the computed property is not called

Comment: so in your actual app, what is attr1 and attr2?

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work fine.

If `attr1` and `attr2` are text.

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
...
totalPrice: computed('attr1', 'attr2', function() {
  return `${this.attr1} ${this.attr2}`;
})
```

`attr1` and `attr2` are number.

```
attr1: 1,
attr2: 2,
totalPrice: computed('attr1', 'attr2', function () {
  return this.attr1 + this.attr2;
  //(or)
  return `${this.attr1 + this.attr2}`;
}),
```

Comment: I think that the `totalPrice` is a computed property that add the two property that will result a `number` so the `return `${this.attr1} ${this.attr2}`;` might not possible. If it's a string then the `return `${this.attr1} ${this.attr2}`;` is applicable because you are combining a two property that are string. I believe he want to add the two number property.

Comment: modified my answer. Separate explanation for both text and number.!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet specifically for ember-cli `3.4`

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember sdfa',

  attr1: 1,
  attr2: 2,
  attr3: 'foo',
  attr4: 'bar',
  attr5: 3,
  attr6: 4,

  totalPrice: computed('attr1', 'attr2',function() {
    let a = this.attr1 ? this.attr1 : 0;
    let b = this.attr2 ? this.attr2 : 0;
    let total = a + b;

    return total;
  }),
});
```

This should work for getting the `totalPrice`, here's the ember twiddle you can play around 
https://ember-twiddle.com/8801e28a888b469b8057d67a63829808?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

If you want to join the string together it should be like this

```
  fooBar: computed('attr3', 'attr4', function() {
    let foo = this.attr3 ? this.attr3 : null;
    let bar = this.attr4 ? this.attr4 : null;

    return `${foo} ${bar}`
  }),
```

and the output would be `foo bar`

If you want to combine a number please follow below

```
combinedNumber: computed('attr5', 'attr6', function() {
    let a = this.attr5 ? this.attr5 : null;
    let b = this.attr6 ? this.attr6 : null;

    return `${a} ${b}`
  }),
```

the output of `combineNumber` is 3 4

Hope it helps.